# IntelliJ text looks HUGE after update to 2019.2

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, ide

I updated IntelliJ to 2019.2 this morning. After the update, all the fonts (actually, fonts and widgets) on the window look absolutely HUGE (even the splashscreen is much bigger when it starts). Main window has the look (in terms of the size of widgets) as being in presentation mode, more or less.

I tried decreasing the size of the fonts in **Settings -> Appearance & Behavior - > Appearance** (set it to 8) and in **Settings -> Font** (also set to 8). And the font in the text editor now is back to *almost* usable (still a little bigger that I'd like) and the menu text as well.... but everything else still looks too big (buttons, tabs, text on the tabs that are on the left side)... so, it's CRAZY. How can I get it back to normal?

I'm on ubuntu 19.04 (actually running KDE) and using OpenJDK.

PS I just downloaded 2019.1 and tried starting it. It looks normal, the way I expect it to. I'm downloading 2019.2 now and let's see what happens what I start it (not from the updated IDE directory).

Just checked starting 2019.2. It looks the way it looked when I started from the updated one. Will stick to using 2019.1 for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the [HiDPI configuration](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007994999) document, there were some changes in handling HiDPI on Linux with the move to JetBrains Runtime 11.

It may help if you switch to the IDE-managed HiDPI mode (legacy mode) by adding

`-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=false`

in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and restarting the IDE.

Comment: I guess this is the culprit. I added the option to the file and it came back to "normal" so I'll stick to using it for a while. Thanks for the tip.